# Android- limit number of push notifications from client side

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I am creating a new app and it gets push notifications well. but now i want to limit the number of push notification from client side(maximum 5). that means when we get 5 push notifications and when we got 6th one, i want to remove 1st.

1. is it possible to do that from client side??

I planed to use local storage(shared preference) to store push notification_id.

2. but the problem is can we access and store push notification data when the app closed time.(As i know there is no any services running when we closed the app app but we get the push notifications) ??

Answer (score 0):

yes we can do this. i used shared preference to store push notification ids and it remove 1st element if we want.(used queue for store push notifications id)